# Entity Framework, select many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select, many-to-many

I am working with Entity Framework code first.

I have the following tables :

```
Companies : PK ID int, Name, ...
Customers : PK ID int, Name, ...
CustomersCompanies : CustomerID, CompanyID
```

I can create customers and companies without problems.
But I don't know how to get all the companies a customer has.

I tried that :

```
_customer = ...
var companies = from c in _db.Companies
                        where c.Customers.Contains(_customer)
                        select c;
```

But companies does not contains anything...

Comment: You don't have `ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }` off the `Customer` model? EF makes it easy to get this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With properly created Entities you should be able to just call:

```
var companies = _customer.Companies;
```

you have to have `ICollection<Company>` within your `Customer` class, and `ICollection<Customer>` within `Company` class.

Check out this tutorial: [Creating a Many To Many Mapping Using Code First](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First).

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare by ID's of customers, like:

```
_customer = ...
var companies = from c in _db.Companies
                    where c.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerID == c.CompanyID)
                    select c;
```

Or shorter:

```
var comapnies = _db.Companies.Select(x => x.CustomerID == c.CompanyID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first you can just add a virtual collection of Companies to your Customer class, and a virtual collection of Customers to your Company class :

```
public class Customer 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

then to fetch customers and include their companies you can do :

```
var customers = _db.Customers.Include(x => x.Companies);
```

I'm not sure what your _db class looks like so I don't know if you just have your entity collections as properties on it. Typically I use the entity framework DbContext which has a GetDbSet method. So I would do something like :

```
var customers = _dbContext.GetDbSet<Customer>().Include(x => x.Companies);
```

Hope that helps!